# Return 401 in a Web API Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

community, I was following an example of how to make a service that offers Facebook login on my web api but I can not make it work.
[The link for the example](http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/?p=1071). I did try the [another example](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/) and still not working.

Well, in my AccountController I have the method GetExternalLogin and in the line:

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
           return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }
```

The method return the error 401. I don't work with OWIN before, but I want in the method call the Facebook Login API. And this don't call the Facebook login page, just return 401.

I copied all the sample code and not worked. What should I do?

The code in the ChallengeResult:

```
 public class ChallengeResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

    public ChallengeResult(string loginProvider, ApiController controller)
    {
        LoginProvider = loginProvider;
        Request = controller.Request;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(LoginProvider);

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        response.RequestMessage = Request;
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

I don't know any thing about OWIN, sorry. I will learn

Comment: hi! i met same behaviour but only with facebook, twitter works fine, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Returning 401 (Unauthorized) is correct. This is what the External Login provider (Facebook in your case) use to know that have to display the login page.

As I see, you are already following a tutorial, but maybe [this one](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/) can help you to understand the authentication and authorization process with external providers. This tutorial explains how to authorize with Google and Facebook, but in your case you can skip the Google parts.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! So, I try the tutorial that you send me, before I did try the tutorial I'm coding now, and this don't work too. The return 
should be the link to login to facebook, not only give 401 error, no? How do I code redirect to facebook if it comes this passage I quoted in the question and die there?

Answer (score 1):

Hit the same problem, burned the same neurons. After losing enough brain mass, I found the cause in my case: In the query string, I have written Facebook with a small f. When I changed it to a capital F, it started working.

Hope this helps.